# What is the difference between LiveData<String>() and LiveData<String?>()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, nullable, nullability

I am new to `LiveData` thing in general and I am having a hard time understanding the difference between `LiveData<String>()` and `LiveData<String?>()`. I used them interchangeably and nothing seams to break. I know that `LiveData.getValue()` is marked with `@Nullable` in Java, so we end up getting `String?` anyway. So what makes `LiveData<String?>()` different from `LiveData<String>()`?

Comment: Because `LiveData` can be constructed without an initial value, `getValue()` can be called before the first value is assigned, so `getValue()` must be nullable. But this doesn't mean you can assign a `null` to the `LiveData` if the type of the `LiveData` is not nullable. If you want the `LiveData` able to be updated to `null` after some non-null value, you have to make its type nullable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up a bit long but I hope it covers everything!

A `LiveData` is meant to be `observe`d. The observer receives data, and the `LiveData`'s *type* says what type that data is. A `LiveData<String>` will *only* supply non-null `String`s to its observers. A `LiveData<String?>` can supply `String`s *and* nulls.

Which of those you want depends on what you're doing! Do you need to supply nulls, e.g. for some kind of *missing* value or whatever? Should they be part of your data? If not, like in any other situation, avoid making the type nullable unless it needs to be.

---

When an observer first `observe`s a `LiveData`, it receives the current value. That way it can immediately handle the current data, update to display the current state, etc. But it's possible for a `LiveData` to *have no value* initially:

```
// non-null
val liveDataWithValue = MutableLiveData<String>("hi")
val emptyLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>()

// nullable
val nullableLiveDataWithValue = MutableLiveData<String?>(null)
val emptyNullableLiveData = MutableLiveData<String?>()
```

The first one there has an initial value. If you observe it, and that value hasn't been updated, the observer will immediately be called with `"hi"` for its parameter.

The second one *has no value*. If you observe that, the observer *won't be called* until a value is set on it. This is useful when you don't actually have any initial data - you can still set up your observer, and nothing will happen until some data is actually pushed.

The third one is the same as the first - it's a nullable `String?` but with a value of *null*. That's *still a value* so if you `observe` it, the observer will immediately be called with that *null*. It's still a piece of data your observer has to react to and process.

The last one is nullable but with no initial value. Like the second one, this means there's nothing for the observer to receive at first - but when it *does* have a value set on it, it could be a *null*. *null* is just another kind of value!

---

But if you go poking around at the `LiveData`'s `value` property, instead of interacting with it through `observe`, then that *no value* state is represented internally by *null*. Java (or at least the version Android targets) doesn't really have a representation of *no value* separate from *null*, so that's just how they have to do things. It just doesn't *publish* anything until you explicitly set a value on it.

So for each of these:

```
val emptyLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>()
val nullableLiveDataWithValue = MutableLiveData<String?>(null)
val emptyNullableLiveData = MutableLiveData<String?>()
```

if you read their `value` in this state, it will be *null* for all of them. One explicitly has a value of *null* set on it, the others are both empty. This also means that **even though `emptyLiveData`'s type is non-null, its `value` property *can* be null**, just because of this "can be empty" situation which is true for all `LiveData` objects. **The nullability of the type is purely about what gets passed to observers**.

You generally shouldn't be reading `value` anyway, except internally (wherever you're actually *setting* the value). Everything else should be interacting with that `LiveData` by observing it and reacting to the values that are published, and those values will be whatever type (nullable or not) that you specified

Answer (score 1):

`LiveData<String?>()` meens that livedata can store null, read please this article to be fully informed: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html

Comment: I know the question mark is for indicating a nullable type. My question is we get ```String?``` with ```LiveData<String>.getValue()``` anyway. Why does ```LiveData<String?>``` exist?

Comment: because LiveData<String> can't store null value, you will got NullPointerException

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: val myLive = LiveData<String>() myLive.value = null //error

Comment: val myLive = LiveData<String?>() myLive.value = null //ok